# Using mathastext with listing

Tags: fonts, listings, mathastext

In the following example code, I would like to use `mathastext` so as to use the same font than the one used by `listings`.

In the code above, the output of the listing do not use a courier-like font, contrarly to to what I'm looking for.

If a solution can be found using `fancyvrb`, that will be also good for my purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
% see section 2.2.3 of the mathastext manual 'sans in math'
\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault
\usepackage{mathastext}
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\lstset{escapechar=\⠶}

\begin{document}

Formulas outside codes don't use a courier like font : $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{5} i^3$.

\begin{lstlisting}
# Evaluation of ⠶ $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{5} i^3$ ⠶
for i in range(5):
    sum += i**3
print sum
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What output you want to obtain is unclear to me.

Comment: @Jubobs I'v just updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear what you want despite the update to your question. Is it something like this?

[image: typewriter maths]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
% see section 2.2.3 of the mathastext manual 'sans in math'
\renewcommand\familydefault\ttdefault
\usepackage{mathastext}
\renewcommand\familydefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}

\lstset{escapechar=\⠶}


\section{Default settings}

\begin{lstlisting}
# Evaluation of ⠶ $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{5} i^3$ ⠶
for i in range(5):
    sum += i**3
print sum
\end{lstlisting}


\section{Use of mathastext ?}

\begin{lstlisting}
# Evaluation of ⠶ $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{5} i^3$ ⠶
for i in range(5):
    sum += i**3
print sum
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very sorry for this so late answer. This is merly what I'm looking for. I have updated my MWE so as to indicate that I just wan to change the font inside listings.